# Some fields are not indexing in apache solr index

Tags: 7, search

I have taxonomy term and date type fields in content type. But they are not displaying in facets list in admin section.

While accessing this url `http://localhost:8983/solr/select` I noted that these fields are not indexing to the apache solr search index.

There is one other taxonomy term reference field and that field is indexing properly.

Any one who have some idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the `search_index` view mode was enabled and I have only enabled that one term reference field in `search_index` therefore only that field was indexing and not others.

So I enabled other fields `search_index` which I wanted to be indexed and it solve my problem.

So if you have enabled this `search_index` view mode for your content type then only those will be indexed which are enabled in this view mode.